Lambda horizontal scaling when consuming from FIFO SQS queue
We have messages which need to be consumed by a lambda. We opted to  use a FIFO SQS queue solely for the deduplication ID feature, but do not otherwise need FIFO features.
The lambda is not scaling horizontally, and we are suspecting that the issue is the single message group that messages are being added to (something like default-message-group). Would creating a unique message group for each message be a valid solution? Is there a more elegant solution?
